# How to implement PHP SoapClient using Soap Endpoint instead of using WSDL?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a requirement to write Soap Client in PHP to call a remote web service and get information. For that I got the Soap End Point URL which doesn't seems to be a WSDL.

I got the WSDL file in the IEPD document set for that Soap services.

When I tried to create new instance of the SoapClient using the End Point it is throwing below error.

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://...' : failed to load external entity "https://.." in..."
```

Can you please help me how should I find WSDL url using an endpoint? or is there any other way I can call the Soap using this end point without getting this error?

To add more reference, I have received the complete documentation of the SOAP webservice in a IEPD document.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you have a look at PHP SoapClient documentation. Start with constructor function SoapClient::SoapClient. There  are examples of non-WSDL usage